# Force typescript not to remove unused references

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, import, reactjs, typescript

Please check my [demo project](https://github.com/aush/react-tfractal) on github.

In my [react-tfractal/tests/component/tfractal.spec.tsx](https://github.com/aush/react-tfractal/blob/master/tests/component/tfractal.spec.tsx) test:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {Tfractal} from '../../src/tfractal';

var R = React;

describe('tfractal', function () {
  it('renders', function () {
    var tfractal = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Tfractal />);
    expect(tfractal).exist;
  });
});
```

`React` import is never used, but required by the `react-addons-test-utils` (I get an error message "React is not defined" without the React import). The problem is: without the line

```
var R = React;
```

this import is removed by the typescript compiler.

The

```
import 'react'
```

doesn't get removed but doesn't work (the same error message "React is not defined").

How can I work around it without creating a dummy variable?

Run

```
npm install
tsd install
npm run test
```

to check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this is happening to be honest, but try adding this line:

```
global.React = React
```

Or even this might work:

```
React;
```